# BroadcastReceiver doesn't work Android 8 API 27

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-mediaplayer

i'm trying to control (Play and Pause ) music from notification my code below works fine on all android version i think expect android 8.1.0 API 27.

BroadcastReceiver :

```
public class MyIntentService extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String RESUME_ACTION = "RESUME_ACTION";
    public static final String STOP_ACTION = "STOP_ACTION";
    public static int REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION = 1212;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() != null) {
            switch (intent.getAction()) {
                case RESUME_ACTION:
                    MApplication.sBus.post(PlaybackEvent.PAUSE);
                    break;
                case STOP_ACTION:
                    MApplication.sBus.post(PlaybackEvent.PLAY);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}


<receiver
            android:name=".MyIntentService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="RESUME_ACTION" />
                <action android:name="STOP_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: you should have `android:name=".MyIntentService"` instead of `android:name=".MyIntentSerice"`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh thanks for your comment but this is just a written mistake

Comment: @ali have you solved the problem ?